# PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'forge' failed

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I want to access a Mysql data the first step is to create a new table for "vanvlymen" and I typed mysql> USE vanvlymen;  the database changed. and type SHOW tables; showing the available of the tables that the database contains.

```
mysql -u root -p 
enter password: ****

mysql> show databases;
-databases-

 information_schema
 mysql
 performance_schema
 phpmyadmin
 vanvlymen

 5 rows...
```

everything is looking good... 
I have decide to tell mysql to specify the database I am working on before executing the query as "vanvlymen"

app/config/database.php

```
   'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'vanvlymen',
        'username'  => 'foobar',
        'password'  => 'foobar',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

save as file go to FileZilla using FTP find a file drag and drop into my live server overwrite the database.php file.

I have tried to clear the cache like that

```
 php artisan cache:clear 

 php artisan migrate
```

it errors:

```
 SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] unknown database 'forge'.
```

Why keeping it said unknown database 'forge' I am excepting to change to vanvlymen database. Should I remove mysql and reinstall?

I am using windows 8.1 with laravel 4.2

Using phpmyadmin, I know what is the password and username to log in.

Comment: Any way you could post the migration file you're using?

Comment: the file migrate is empty. I was working on my local but I have not put all the files into live migrate on FileZilla as yet...when I do that its sightly difference as "[1045] access denied for user 'forge'@localhost' (using password: NO)."

Comment: I went to back app/config/database.php on FileZilla by the click right button looking for view/edit open the file. looking for the on the lists database change to "vanvlymen" and the username, password are from phpmyadmin make sure its connect approate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have something like app/config/*yourEnvironment*/database.php ?
For example *local* or *production*. 'forge' is default name of DB in this config file, so it looks like your app is loading wrong config file.

Answer (score 1):

remove two files `config.php` and `services.php` in `/bootstrap/cache`. And try again.

Comment: Add what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else. I suddenly had an issue where my dev site I was building stopped connecting to the DB, and just as the OP it was saying:

```
PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'forge' failed
```

After much head scratching (!) I found that my hostname value set inside the /bootstrap/start.php was wrong, because my hostname had changed on my macbook pro!? I have no idea how but it changed from something like `RobMacbookPro2.local` to `RobMacbookPro.local`. This meant it fell back to production thus loading the incorrect database.php file with the standard DB=forge (which was wrong)

Check this guide:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration

Pay particular attention to the code:

```
<?php

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('your-machine-name'),

));
```

On a mac and probably linux? you can determine your hostname by typing `# hostname` in terminal.

Hope that saves someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running both Xampp and MySQL Workbench, or if You are Running Xampp on the port other than the default port, there may be chances of confusion, you may have created the database using PHPMyAdmin and you are trying to connect it to localhost:*cusotmport* (e.g. localhost:8080).
 what I suggest is to create the database you want using MySQL workbench and then you would get your task done...