# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'previous_db_name'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this error when i use `php artisan migrate` in my Laravel project.

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'previous_db_name'
```

this is my `database.php` file :

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'current_db_name'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
],
```

I saw this error in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119818/laravel-pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-1049-unknown-database-forge) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421626/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-1049-unknown-database-forge-failed) but none of them was not helpful.

Comment: For me, I suddenly needed to change my `.env` to use `DB_PORT=33060` even though it used to work with 3306. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756918/470749 Maybe it was related to upgrading the Vagrant box.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It clearly mentions that there's no such database named **previous_db_name**.

From what it seems the *database.php* file is not where the variable is from.

Check the [.env](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration) file in your Laravel installation folder to see if that's the database name that you have wrongly specified.

Answer (score 7):

Please run this command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 6):

`php artisan cache:clear`

AND

restart your server

I had to kill my server and re-run `php artisan serve` for my project to register the change of my DB_DATABASE name.  I kept getting the error even after clearing the cache because I didn't realize this.

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.x You should define the DB Details in two files

1. `.env` file in the project folder
2. `.database.php` file inside `config` folder

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP artisan serve just restart it. (just in case someone comes searching as I did).

Answer (score 1):

set your database name in .env file too.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it is super late but for people like me, new in laravel and following tutorial from artisansweb. Note that, migrate will not create your database. Rather, it will just create all the tables. Assuming, you have set up your .env file. Now the important part is create the database and users (if you decided to go with custom users) manually. Then, do the **php artisan migrate command**

hope that helps.

Comment: This helped me! Coming from Ruby on Rails, I was expecting a command similar to `rails db:create` and just realised there isn't such thing in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
    class Config {
      private $host = "localhost";
      private $db_name = "db_ahp";
      private $username = "root";
      private $password = "";
      public $conn;
    
      public function getConnection() {
        $this->conn = null;
        try {
          $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
          echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->conn;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but I am just updating in case someone else faces a similar issue. I came across the same error, in my case it happened to be due to a missing database in xampp. i.e I was literally running a migration on an **inexisting database in xampp**.

0. Kill your server in case it's running. (Use **Ctrl+C** on windows.)
1. Make sure that you created the actual DB in your phpMyAdmin.
2. Run the following command to clear the cache: `php artisan cache:clear`
3. Run `php artisan migrate` once again.

Everything should be good after this.

Happy coding.