# Unknown database error when I run php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have cloned one of my larval projects on to another laptop and I have run composer install, php artisan key:generate. I have changed the .env file to create the database.  When I run php artisan migrate I get the following error

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                  
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'student' (SQL: select * from   information_schema.tables where table_schema = student and table_name =migrations)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689376/laravel-sqlstatehy000-1049-unknown-database-previous-db-name)

Comment: You don't have a `student` database on the new laptop.

Comment: Forgive the stupid question how do I create the database on the new laptop.  I have tried setting it up in Sequel Pro ?

Comment: https://research.bowdoin.edu/digital-computational-studies/student-research/sql/sequel-pro-creating-a-database/

Comment: Not having much luck with this.  I don't know why this is not working?

Comment: Do you have the database created? You just need to create one with the name student and then run the `php artisan migrate` command

Comment: Make sure you have existing database (student) in your laptop

before migration

Comment: Are you using the Homestead environment if so - [Sequel Pro & Homestead](https://tannerhearne.com/using-sequel-pro-laravel-homestead/)

Comment: No I am not using Homestead.

Comment: The error looks perfectly straight-forward: your configuration is set to use the student database, and the student database doesn't exist (or the user configured for laravel doesn't have access to it).  Have you created the database yet?  A few people have asked, but you haven't answered.  If so, then we are going to need lots more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php artisan migrate` command doesn't create the database for you. [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/creating-a-database-with-php-artisan?page=1) is a potential way you can do it with the command.
Other wise create it [manually](https://research.bowdoin.edu/digital-computational-studies/student-research/sql/sequel-pro-creating-a-database/).

Comment: Thanks Rbaskam. I was being an idiot about creating the database in Sequel Pro.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help.