# Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting the error below even though my *Controller* class is present in my Controllers directory;

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

Below is the content of my *UserController* controller (in the same directory, Controllers):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function SignIn(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['usernameEmail'=>$request['usernameEmail'],'password'=>$request['password']])) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function getDashBoard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` and try agin

Comment: Btw, you're in the same namespace, so you don't need to specify the use statement.

Comment: tried composer dump-autoload  but still getting the same error.

Comment: Removing the 'use' statement did not help either @Treast

Comment: I didn't say it gonna resolve your problem, just clean a little your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found`
 error because you have no such a class in your project at the derived location.

Instead of

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; // this is irrelevant and causing the error you get
```

you should have

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // this is necessary for your SingIn method
```

as in:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // your methods here
}
```

because one of your `SignIn` method does make use of it.

Comment: @K142084ArsalanMehmood: What error do you get after following my recommendation? Is it the same as you've reported in your post above?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'healthapp' (SQL: select * from `users` where `usernameEmail` = ahmer limit 1)
in Connection.php 
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `users` where `usernameEmail` = ? limit 1', array('ahmer'), object(Closure))
in Connection.php

Comment: @K142084ArsalanMehmood: Then it means my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45259072/6381711) truly answered your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45252723/6381711) as you no longer get the `Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found` error after following my suggested recommendation. What you should do: mark my post as the answer to your question, then, ask a new question with the new error you get and share the link here in comments so I take a look at it. Let a new question be a new post.

Comment: @K142084ArsalanMehmood: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33689445/6381711) should guide you resolve the new error you are getting; you have to check your `database.php` file in your `config` folder as well as your `.env` file (in the root directory of your project); do make sure your database exist, then define the connection parameters to it so as to enable your Laravel app access it.

Answer (score 0):

It you ran `composer dump-autoload` and it didn't fixed your problem you placed your controller in wrong folder. It should be inside `app\Http\Controllers` dir.

If it won't fix your issue, look at `storage\logs\laravel.log` where you can find more informations about the problem, and where your problem occured. Maybe you are defining routes using wrong classname or something like that.